# How do I see more of the command line with the KDE System Guard Process Table

Tags: kde, process

I often have several java programs running and I can't tell which one needs to be killed. The command section of the process table only shows java, but doesn't tell me which jar or class files it is running.
Edit: Is there a way to see more of the command call from withing KSysGuard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ps aux | grep java`
2. You look for the Process ID(PID) of the process you want and then you use kill command (for how to use kill read my post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684/kill-java-doesnt-kill-java/710#710))

Also read: [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1251234&postcount=4) and [here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_find_all_child_processes_in_unix.html) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jc/entry/kill_java_process)

An alternative: `ps -fp $(pgrep -d, -x java)` or you might use [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) or [top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) and search for java

Comment: Something staying with ksysguard would be prefered.

Answer (score 1):

A GUI alternative to Ksysguard is [qps](http://qps.kldp.net/projects/qps). It's perhaps less visually appealing that ksysguard, but it shows a lot more information, including the whole command line.

Answer (score 0):

You want the wide output option "w". Using it three times will allow unlimited width.

```
ps auxwww
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to see more of the command within ksysguard.